# How to change Ruby Version for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Having some serious issues with Ruby at the moment and I have a feeling it's around versioning.

I have a Gemfile that looks like this

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.5.2"

gem "rails", "4.2.1"
gem "unicorn", "4.8.3"
gem "mysql2"
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.3"
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
gem "turbolinks"
gem "ancestry"
gem "kaminari"
gem "saxerator"
gem "factory_girl_rails"
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
gem "tree_delta", "~> 2.0.0"
gem "daemons"
gem "which-user",      git: "https://ad131a5ab23a69365434b0e7e36d6275b6a1e9fb:x-oauth-basic@github.com/whichdigital/which-user.git", ref: '18eb7'
gem "eva_rails",       git: "https://ad131a5ab23a69365434b0e7e36d6275b6a1e9fb:x-oauth-basic@github.com/whichdigital/eva_rails.git", tag: "v1.0.6"
gem "dam_client",      git: "https://ad131a5ab23a69365434b0e7e36d6275b6a1e9fb:x-oauth-basic@github.com/whichdigital/digital_asset_manager_client.git", tag: "1.0.0"
gem "fragment_client", git: "https://ad131a5ab23a69365434b0e7e36d6275b6a1e9fb:x-oauth-basic@github.com/whichdigital/fragment_client.git", ref: '3c197'
gem 'frontend_containers', git: "https://ad131a5ab23a69365434b0e7e36d6275b6a1e9fb:x-oauth-basic@github.com/whichdigital/frontend_containers.git"
gem "cucumber-rails", require: false
gem "parallel_tests"
gem "elasticsearch"
gem 'patron'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'net-http-persistent'
gem "dalli"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "newrelic_rpm"
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
gem 'mail'
gem 'rack-rewrite', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'httparty'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem "timecop"
  gem "webmock"
  gem "site_prism"
  gem "simplecov", require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "rspec-its"
  gem "shoulda-matchers", require: false
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-commands-rspec"
  gem "spring-commands-cucumber"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "pry-byebug"
  gem "rubocop", require: false
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "poltergeist"
  gem "capybara-firebug"
  gem "capybara-screenshot"
  gem "yarjuf"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "web-console", "~> 2.0"
  gem "bullet"
  gem "rspec-collection_matchers"
  gem "eyes_selenium"
  gem 'ftpd'
end
```

I have `Bundler version 1.11.2` installed.

Gem version `2.4.6`

Rails `4.2.5.1`

When I execute `ruby -v` I get this returned `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

The read me file that came with this project said to run `"bin/setup"` which then prompted me to install `bundler`. Installed as you see above.

As that command is running I get the following error `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.2`

I cannot for some reason update to this version.

If anyone needs anymore information please let me know.

Comment: Well for a start the current latest ruby version is `2.3.0` so your line `ruby "2.5.2"` needs changing.  Not sure where you have got that from

Comment: Client sent this through which is odd - going back to them to revise.

Comment: Following the pattern of the last few releases, Ruby 2.5.0 is going to be released on Christmas Eve, 2017, with 2.5.2 probably somewhere around Summer to Fall 2017. Maybe the client is planning ahead and expects you to take that long to get set up?

Comment: Maybe rubinius rather than MRI ruby?

Answer (score 8):

Try changing the ruby version in your Gemfile.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.5.2"
# ...
```

to:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.0.0"
# ...
```

also, from what I had gathered and as mentioned in part above, latest stable version of ruby is 2.3.0 atm in case that may of interest

Comment: Thanks for the post here Drew. I have successfully updated my ruby version to 2.2.2 - I assume to update the 1st line in the gemfile to point to the same version? I've questioned the client about the 2.5 version

Comment: welcome. and if I had to guess would be general scheme

Comment: Ok this has worked a treat - also may have helped I started a new terminal window. Only thing now I'm getting is the following: "An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue." I am noting that in the gem file there is no version next to mysql2? Could that be an issue here?

Comment: or particular error in the sense of I wonder if there had also been a more specific error present in log? or thoughts? also, if I had to guess would get latest version if no version specified, in case that may be of interest. also, it's okay--could have most definitely clarified!

Comment: This is the error that got returned: 

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: gotcha. I wonder if you have mysql installed? maybe brew install mysql?

Comment: Edited - its a bit easier to read when you cut it down to the essentials instead of just copy pasting the whole file. Also changed the phasing slightly, feel free to revert if you don't agree.